# Is it still possible, as of Version 1.2.0, to change the max numbers of players for Risk of Rain's Online Co-Op?

Tags: risk-of-rain

Exactly what it says on the tin. I have heard of up to 10 players. But, when my friends and I used the change max_players_online in Prefs.ini method to change the max players in online Co-Op to 8, it would not allow us to do so.

Has this functionality been patched out? Or is there another method that we can use?

Thank you, in advance, for your time.

Comment: It should work but I can't find any solid proof. I'd try it myself, except I don't have enough friends to do so .-.